# referencing a url like src="//www.example.com/blah.js"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen references for images and .js files like:

```
src="//www.example.com..."
```

is this a technique so it works in both http and https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. If you leave off the protocol, most modern browsers will use whatever is being used by the current page.